# How to solve an optimization problems of this kind?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, simplex

I have to solve a real-world optimization problem. I am teaching 33 students, a university lesson, and I am attempting to assign them 11 semester projects, based on their preference. I grouped them in 11 teams of 3 students per team, and asked them to state their 3 most preferenced projects.

Let student groups be $X_i , \text{where } i \in [1,11]$ and semester projects be $Y_i , \text{where } i \in [1,11]$

$X_1 \text{ chose in order of priority the projects } Y_7, Y_1, Y_10$ 
$X_2 \text{ chose in order of priority the projects } Y_2, Y_7, Y_6$ 
$... etc ...$

For simplicity's shake I will map this onto a matrix (columns = assignments, rows = groups, values = preferences)

\begin{matrix}
 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
\end{matrix}

---

This is an integer programming problem (I think?). How can this problem be solved? Is there an algorithm for that kind of optimization problems? I am missing knowledge here.

Comment: You need to define an objective: how do you trade-off preferences between groups?

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks for the observation. The first (upper) rows have priority, because they stated their preference faster

Comment: That is still too vague. If you can give 5 groups their first choice and 6 groups their third choice, is that better than giving 11 groups all their second choice? You need to answer those kind of questions first before you look for an algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [(balanced) assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), which is what you probably have here (assuming you choose a suitable objective function, per LinAlg's comment).

Comment: I used the Hungarian method. It worked flawlessly. The problem can also be modeled and solved with Simplex. The restrictions are that no team will take more than one project, and no project will be taken by more than one team. $\sum_{i=1}^{11} x_{ij} = 1 $ and $\sum_{j=1}^{11} x_{ij} = 1 $, where $i$ the teams and $j$ the projects. We define as profit the preference and we try to maximize it: $\sum_{i=1}^{11}\sum_{j=1}^{11} p_{ij}\cdot x_{ij}$